# SVN can't add Apache created folders

Tags: svn, apache, joomla, file-permissions

I am building a Joomla site that is managed by SVN. When extensions are installed via the Joomla admin panel, Joomla will create folders that I want to add to SVN, but these folders are created by the Apache user and I do not have write permission or root access, which prevents SVN from adding '.svn' directories within. Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the svn user in the same group as apache
so svn will have the permissions to add the folders to svn

or a ignore but then the folders will not be added to svn only ignored

Comment: What if I don't have permission to do that?

Comment: Then you can give the folders the permissions 777 but then you must know everyone with permissions on that server can access that folder

or you can try to change the owner from apache to your ftp user maybe you have permissions to do that

with both options svn have access to the files / folders

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Joomla on Linux, you want to enable the [FTP layer](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/1941/302/1/2/) to make handling file permissions easier.  If you don't have permissions to be the Apache user, than you need to find an admin to help you out whenever you have problems.  The FTP layer avoids that.  If you're running Joomla in a DirectAdmin environment, go to the file manager to reset the owner on any Apache owned directory.